# Trouble using NFC in a customer Credential Provider

Tags: c#, c++, windows, nfc, credential-providers

So I'm trying to get my custom windows credential provider to log in using NFC (not with third party apps, please don't recommend this).

I need it to work with the Windows.Networking.Proximity library, which works fine in the test script I wrote in VB, and also in the DLL I made in C#, however I'm not too sure how to go about adding it to the credential provider.

I've tried adding the DLL I made to the credential provider using LoadLibrary, although this didn't work, and may have something to do with the credential provider not liking .NET.

I'm also looking into just trying to start the service Windows uses to detect NFC reads, but I'm having trouble locating which process it's using.

Has anyone had any experience with this kind of thing, as Google doesn't seem to be proving too helpful?

Many thanks,

Rowan

(EDIT: this is based off of Microsoft's Sample Credential Provider V2)